# Evaluate json expression in mybatis

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, mybatis

I have JSON column in my sql server table. I need to execute some filter on the column and execute a query

Below is the SQL

```
select 
   count(*)
   <if test="filter==dept"> ,json_extract(hierarchy,'$.dept_desc') as groupCol</if>
   <if test="filter==catg"> ,json_extract(hierarchy,'$.catg_desc') as groupCol</if>
from 
    table_1
group by
   <if test="filter==dept"> ,json_extract(hierarchy,'$.dept_desc') as groupCol</if>
   <if test="filter==catg"> ,json_extract(hierarchy,'$.catg_desc') as groupCol</if>;
```

I am getting an error with `There is no getter for property named 'dept_desc'.` 
Without the  condition query is working. I tried keeping if condition inside `<![CDATA[]]` also but error remains same.

Comment: Does the query run outside of MyBatis?

Comment: Yes....query works as expcted outside mybatis. Below is the query 

select count(*), json_value(hierarchy,'$.dept_desc) as group_col from table_1 grouo by json-value(hierarchy,'$.dept_desc);

Answer (score 1):

Dollar sign is a special symbol in mybatis, it is used for variables expansion. In this case mybatis treats `$.dept_desc` as an expression accessing object property.

You can use [CDATA section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML) to disallow mybatis interpret text including dollar sign:

```
<if test="filter==dept"><![CDATA[ ,json_extract(hierarchy,'$.dept_desc') as groupCol ]]>
```